# ews-javascript-api Find Items does not return anything

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm using [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/) to connect to outlook exchange and read mails.

I need to download the attachment.

However, when I run the `FindItems` query, it returns with 0 items.

```
var ews = require('ews-javascript-api');
var ExchangeService = ews.ExchangeService;
var service = new ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new ews.ExchangeCredentials("MY_USERNAME", "MY_PASSWORD");
service.Url = new ews.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");

var items = service.FindItems(ews.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "hasattachment:true",new ews.ItemView(1));

items.then(function (response)
{
    console.log("__________________________");

    console.log(response);
},function(err){
    console.log("ERROR");
});
```

I'm unable to understand why its happening. Does it only get the unread emails?

**Output:**

```
 FindItemsResults {
  totalCount: 0,
  nextPageOffset: null,
  moreAvailable: false,
  items: [],
  highlightTerms: [] }
```

Comment: What happens when you do not use the keyword? (hasattachment....)

Comment: still it has the same output. is it the right way to give that condition?

Comment: You want to check debug log and soap data to make sure it is being construct ed properly

Comment: actually, it looks like some problem with a specific server. When I used my personal ID, its sending me items, but when I use a client's id, it does not. But that server sent response for the C# code

Comment: Can you turn on tracing in c# to check what is the soap xml and header information. Compare with js version of soap. It will clear the issue